# How to create custom navigation using Magento category links - Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, navigation, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento and currently using the Magento 1.9.

Problem :- I have two type of Menus one is Main menu and other is Mobile menu on my website . I have customized the topMenu html to fill the requirement of Main menu but I am not able to find a way to fetch category links and create Mobile menu inside a different Content Block.

Comment: The file I used to customize main menu is as given below:                 /public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/st/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem. During my R&D I did found multiple solutions of the problem which are listed below.

1. The basic and most easy solution is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt1ZF8mQxk4
2. You can also achieve the same thing by creating a content block and including following code:

   ```
   <?php
   $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory(); 
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_category->entity_id);
   $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
   ?>

   <ul>
   <?php foreach ($collection as $cat):?>
       <?php if($_category->getIsActive()):?>
           <?php 
                $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
                $_img = $cur_category->getImageUrl();  
           ?>
           <li>
               <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($cat);?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $_img?>" title="$cat->getName()"/>
                    <cite><?php echo $cat->getName();?></cite>
               </a>
           </li>
       <?php endif?>
   <?php endforeach;?>
   </ul>
   ```

Thanks & Happy Coding !!